# Magento Admin Panel Missing or Broken - See Screenshots

Tags: magento

We were doing typical content edits and the admin panel had the regular functionality and styling. 
When we finished and logged out and then in again....We got just a file tree...the links withing the tree just loop back to the original page when you click on them... There is no way to edit anything...Please Help!

Using Magento ver. 1.5.1.0

Thank you!

james

SCREEN SHOT: http://goo.gl/nhaJS

Comment: *****Guys,Thank you so much --- I have attempted to trouble shoot using your advice but I am a Magento novice and fear I would break things further -- The actual site is working = I just can't make edits which I really need to. --- Is there anyone that can take a look and maybe fix things up and perhaps update too a more recent version? - james.lynch@konnessi.com

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable CSS/JS minification recently? The default functionality to handle this can be dodgy if your settings aren't just right. My reasoning with this answer would be that it appears you aren't loading any CSS or JS correctly.

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%merge%';`

You should get two results. Try setting them to 0 if they are enabled, and then remove your /var/ folder to clear cache.

Further troubleshooting would include disabling modules if you had installed any recently. Barring that, take a gander at Firebug and look at which paths are being built to your CSS/JS files. That should give us a big clue.

Answer (score 0):

Erase everything in `/var/cache/` and `/var/session/`

Looks like you may have left the trailing slash off of your domain name in your `Base URL`.  Go to `System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Unsecure -> Base URL` and make sure it ends with `/`.  Repeat for `Secure`.

Answer (score 0):

Check file permissions on the media and var directories.  They need to be writable by the webserver user.  You probably enabled merging of JS and CSS and apache can't write to media/css media/css_secure and/or media/js